# Unable to connect Bluetooth in nougat socket closed

Tags: android, android-bluetooth

[image]i have successfully import the google sample Bluetooth chat project and fix  run time permission but unable to connect the device. socket closed i tried lot but unfortunately can't fix this please help to fix this issue

Comment: what about some code? Log from Logcat? something... :)

Comment: Please check below code

Answer (score 0):

My personal experience with this “java.io.IOException: read failed, socket might closed or timeout, read ret: -1”

In my case. The blue-tooth device is connected to another device and tested the connection. Later, I disconnected the connection from another device and try to connect to my device but, connection is not established.

After turn-on & turn-off of device several time. my device is connected to blue-tooth device.

Even the device is disconnected. The address of the device connection were not removed from device. I was using barcode scanner device.

There is a possibility like this. Please check once by turning off and on and also reset the bluetooth device.

Try like this

```
try {
mmSocket = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"));
mmSocket.connect();
} catch (IOException e) {
Log.d(TAG, "Fail Attempt1 : " + e.toString());

    try{
         mmSocket =(BluetoothSocket) mmDevice.getClass().getMethod("createInsecureRfcommSocket", new Class[] {int.class}).invoke(mmDevice,1);
         mmSocket.connect();
        } catch (Exception e1){
            try {
                    mmSocket.close();
                } catch (IOException e5) {
}
```

Comment: yes i have tried also put 2 instead of 1 but same exception appear

Comment: In my case. I'm experiencing the same situation now als. If i connect bluetooth device with another mobile. It wont connect to mine. I use to turn off & on the bluetooth device many time. at some instance it ll connect.

Comment: please check the attached image in question

Comment: your are expecting send & receive connection or only receive connection through bluetooth ?

Comment: I would like to add one more changes. Call mChatService.connect(mDevice); at receiver "BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDED". after pairing of device the connection will start to establish

Comment: send and receive